# Insert into with returning into :array

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle, sql-returning

i want to add multiple rows to table in oracle and get back added values to python list

the returned column is the primary key and is generated on the oracle side

the code I wrote doesn't work, which is understandable, but I don't know how to write otherwise. help me please

```
out_id = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

batch = []
for i in range(3):
    batch.append({'val': i})

ins = 'INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (:val) RETURNING table.col2 into :out_id'

cursor.executemany(ins, batch)

print(list_out_id.getvalue())
```

I get an error

ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

Comment: Can you please let us know what version of cx_Oracle you are using? What is the error that you are getting? Also please use cursor.var() instead of cursor.arrayvar() for the out variable `list_out_id`.
The [array variable](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.arrayvar) created with `cursor.arrayvar()` can only be used for PL/SQL associative arrays with contiguous keys. For executing RETURNING INTO DML Statement on cx_Oracle, please read through the following docs:
[https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#dml-returning-bind-variables](

Comment: @Sharad i use version of cx_Oracle 8.0.1. I changed my code in the description of the question

Answer (score 0):

@e.burenina
A few observations here:

- I am assuming col2 is an AUTO INCREMENT Number field
- I am assuming you meant to use *out_id* instead of *list_out_id* in the last line
- *arraysize* parameter should be included when you define the cursor variable out-id. i.e., `out_id = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER,arraysize=3)`.
- *cx_Oracle.NUMBER* will return any number in Python float format(e.g., 0.0, 1.0 etc.). So if the returned data is an integer,
  please use `out_id = cursor.var(int,arraysize=3)`
- The *batch* list should include both the input 'val' and the output variable *out_id*
  `batch.append({'val':i,'out_id':out_id})`

The following code should return the required values:

```
import cx_Oracle
# Establish the database connection - Add your DB details here
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="hr", password="hr", dsn="localhost/orclpdb")

# Obtain a cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

# set the input and output variables
out_id = cursor.var(int, arraysize=3)
batch = []
for i in range(3):
    batch.append({'val': i, 'out_id': out_id})

# set the SQL statement
ins = 'INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES (:val) RETURNING table.col2 into :out_id'

# run the query and fetch the output into 'out_id' variable
cursor.executemany(ins, batch)

# print the out_id in a list
print(out_id.values)
```

*Note*: Please ensure that you do a `connection.commit()` at the end, in case you want to commit your code changes to the DB

Also make changes to the *arraysize* parameter based on the number of rows returned by your INSERT statement.

Comment: thanks for your reply! but I get all the return values on each row

, and I would like to get a separate return value for each added record

Comment: instead of
[{'val': 1, 'out_id': <cx_Oracle.Var of type DB_TYPE_NUMBER with value [[id_1], [id_2], [id_3]]}, {...}, {...}]
this is
[{'val': 1, 'out_id': id_1}, {'val': 2, 'out_id': id_2}, {...}]

Comment: I am confused here...Are you trying to output the `batch` variable or just the `out_id` variable as a list? 
If it is the 'batch' variable, Do you want to output the in the following format :`[{'val':1, 'out_id':id_1},{'val':2, 'out_id':id_2}, {....})
Please give an example of the current output that you are getting and the expected output?

Comment: @e.burenina, Can you please let me know if this problem is solved...
It would be helpful to solve the problem , if you reply to my previous comment as well

Comment: i did as described here https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/efficient-and-scalable-batch-statement-execution-in-python-cx_oracle

Comment: out_id = cursor.var(int, arraysize=len(batch))
cursor.setinputsizes(out_id=out_id)
cursor.executemany(insert, batch)

for i, inputRow in enumerate(batch):
    inputRow['id'] = out_id.getvalue(i)[0]

Comment: @e.burenina - `setinputsizes()` should be used when we use lists or lists for inputs. Here we are using a list of dicts, `setinputsizes()` will not be useful. I have added a sample code in my latest answer that may solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

For printing output in the format

> [{'val': 1, 'out_id': id_1}, {'val': 2, 'out_id': id_2}, {...}]

the following code will work

```
import cx_Oracle
# Establish the database connection - Add your DB details here 
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(
    user="hr", password="hr", dsn="localhost/orclpdb")

# Obtain a cursor cursor = connection.cursor()

# set the input and output variables
out_id = cursor.var(int, arraysize=3)
batch = []
for i in range(3):
    batch.append({'val': i, 'out_id': out_id})    

# set the SQL statement
ins = 'INSERT INTO table(col1) VALUES (:val) RETURNING table.col2 into :out_id'

# run the query and fetch the output into 'out_id' variable 
cursor.executemany(ins, batch)

#print the output in the required format
for i in range(3):
    batch[i]['out_id'] = batch[i]['out_id'].getvalue(i)
print(batch) 
print(out_id.values)
# Do a commit to the table if required
# connection.commit()
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I wanted, because I will add a huge bunch of data, it will work for me for a long time compared to executemany

Comment: @e.burenina Do you need to use `executemany` instead of `execute`? Is that a requirement here?

Comment: @e.burenina, I have updated the code in the answer above so that it uses `executemany` instead of `execute` for inserting the data and getting the output in the required format.